# How to configure client certificate to test two way SSL using Jmeter?

Tags: ssl-certificate, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am setting up Jmeter 2.11 to test web application involving SSL client certificate.

Below is what I've tried out, which is not working

Steps:

1)  Java 1.7 installed and classpath configured

2)  Download Jmeter and Unzip  Jmeter

3)  Open browser, hit the https (SSL) site that you want to test

4)  Select the Root CA and export it in .der format

5) Now using java keytool.exe converted file to .jks

```
   keytool -importcert -alias mycert -file exportedFile.der  -keystore Convertedtruststore.jks -storepass password
```

6)  Copied the file in jmeter dir and updated system.properties from jmeter/bin

```
       javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/Convertedtruststore.jks
```

7) Copied .pfx certificate (cert for login authentication)

8) Using Jetty, Run below command to convert .pfx file to .jks file

```
     java -classpath jetty-6.1.22.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.PKCS12Import AdminCert.pfx   AdminKeystore.jks
```

9) Updated system.properties from jmeter/bin

```
  javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/Admin_Keystore.jks

  javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

10) Start jmeter from jmeter/bin/jmeter.bat

11) Created thread, added Firefox config element and Sample. Inserted the following script to launch the application

```
  WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
  WDS.browser.get('https://idc-cic-console.symclab.net/console/view/wall');
  WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

As soon as the browser opens, it throws an error "Secure connection failed. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters"

The site opens fine when launched manually inside the browser.

Please let me know if there is anything I missed to configure?

Comment: have you found a solution to that?